# Extract a part of image

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emgucv

I am trying to extract black screen from an image so I used `canny` filter. Then I found out that I need to extract the second largest contour to detect the part I want. Here the code to filter:

```
  private void cannyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( imageInput == null)
         {
             return;
         }
        Image<Gray, byte> imageCanny = new Image<Gray, byte>(imageInput.Width, imageInput.Height, new Gray(1));
        imageCanny = imageInput.Canny(80, 20);

        imageBox2.Image = imageCanny; }
```

Now I don't know how I extract the part I want from the image! Need help and thank you.

Comment: Can you post the image?

Comment: Yes of course : https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8Qbe.png